# Running docker pipeline in snakemake using singularity without specifying singularity exec docker://

Tags: docker, snakemake, singularity-container

I'm trying to tie scripts from an existing pipeline on docker into my snakemake pipeline. I have the docker pipeline set up using singularity and it works. For instance,

```
singularity exec docker://mypipeline some_command.sh file.bam out_file.bam
```

works perfectly when I run it interactively on the command line. Similarly, when I incorporate the exact same command into my Snakefile it also works:

```
rule myrule:
        input:
                "file.bam"
        output:
                "out_file.bam"
        shell:
                "singularity exec docker://mypipeline some_command.sh {input} {output}"
```

However, when I try to follow this tutorial https://reproducibility.sschmeier.com/container/index.html#using-a-container-in-our-workflow to incorporate the container into my workflow as follows

```
singularity: "docker://mypipeline"

rule myrule:
    input:
            "file.bam"
    output:
            "out_file.bam"
    shell:
            "some_command.sh {input} {output}"
```

And I run `snakemake -p --use-singularity --cores 1` I get the following output

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       myrule
        1

[Sun May 17 15:28:11 2020]
rule myrule:
    input: file.bam
    output: out_file.bam
    jobid: 0

some_command.sh file.bam out_file.bam
Activating singularity image myImage.simg
```

Then I get a very long report that I'm not sure what to make of, followed by this error message

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 3 of Snakefile:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds:
out_file.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2020-05-17T152810.484310.snakemake.log
```

My questions:

- Why does one work and not the other/how can I get the last example to work?
- Is it good practice to declare `singularity: "docker://...` upfront or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

Error message suggests singularity command got executed successfully but snakemake doesn't see the output file. Is the output file `out_file.bam` shown in your code same as the one you actually use, or you removed some filepath? I would suggest adding `--verbose` flag to snakemake and reviewing the actual singularity command that snakemake executes.

Comment: I did remove some file paths just to make it easier to read. The paths are correct though. I believe I figured out the source of the error: the pipeline I'm using appears to be adding a prefix to the file that I'm creating (and I have not been adding this prefix to the output file name, hence: missing output files). Still troubleshooting this. I'm still curious as to why I don't get the error when I add `singularity exec docker://mypipeline...` infront though, any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked how the singularity command executed by snakemake (obtained by using `--verbose` flag) compared to your own `singularity exec` command? That would be my first step to see how/if output filepaths differ.

Comment: Yes, both are the same as far as I can tell. This is what -p returns:
`some_command.sh file.bam out_file.bam` and this is what the --verbose flag returns:
`singularity exec --home /mywd  --bind /home/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/mnt/snakemake /mywd/.snakemake/singularity/myImage.simg bash -c 'set -euo pipefail;  some_command.sh file.bam out_file.bam'`